libgpiod version 2.x.x on Docker container error for : conditional "HAS_GI_DOCGEN" was never defined
I'm building a Docker container that use libgpiod version 2.x.x and my own C++ code.
Dockerfile:

# Start with a Debian-based image
FROM debian:bookworm-slim

# Install necessary tools for building from source
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    git \
    cmake \
    pkg-config \
    libtool \
    autoconf \
    doxygen \
    help2man \
    automake 

RUN apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Clone the libgpiod repository
RUN git clone https://github.com/brgl/libgpiod.git /tmp/libgpiod

# Build and install libgpiod version 2
RUN cd /tmp/libgpiod && \
    ./autogen.sh && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig

# Clean up build dependencies
RUN apt-get remove -y \
    build-essential \
    git \
    cmake \
    pkg-config \
    libtool \
    autoconf \
    doxygen \
    help2man \
    automake
    
RUN apt-get autoremove -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/libgpiod

# Set a working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Add your project files (optional)
# COPY . /app

# Define the entry point (optional)
# CMD ["your_command_here"]


When building the container I'm getting the following error:
$ docker build --no-cache  -t docker_test . 
 
[+] Building 99.5s (8/11)                                  docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.09kB                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:bookworm-slim    0.9s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/debian:bookworm-slim@sha256:2ccc7  0.0s
 => [2/8] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y     build-essenti  81.8s
 => [3/8] RUN apt-get clean &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*             0.5s 
 => [4/8] RUN git clone https://github.com/brgl/libgpiod.git /tmp/libgpio  2.8s 
 => ERROR [5/8] RUN cd /tmp/libgpiod &&     ./autogen.sh &&     make &&   13.4s 
------                                                                          
 > [5/8] RUN cd /tmp/libgpiod &&     ./autogen.sh &&     make &&     make install &&     ldconfig:                                                              
0.433 autoreconf: export WARNINGS=                                              
0.436 autoreconf: Entering directory '.'                                        
0.439 autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext                               
1.440 autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
1.637 aclocal: warning: couldn't open directory 'm4': No such file or directory
5.215 autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
6.950 autoreconf: configure.ac: creating directory autostuff
6.950 autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
7.176 libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, 'autostuff'.
7.176 libtoolize: copying file 'autostuff/ltmain.sh'
7.260 libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
7.260 libtoolize: copying file 'm4/libtool.m4'
7.342 libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
7.414 libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
7.473 libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
7.551 libtoolize: copying file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
7.655 autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Intltool
7.655 autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gtkdoc
7.655 autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
11.39 autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
12.56 configure.ac:77: warning: The macro `AC_HEADER_STDC' is obsolete.
12.56 configure.ac:77: You should run autoupdate.
12.56 ./lib/autoconf/headers.m4:704: AC_HEADER_STDC is expanded from...
12.56 configure.ac:77: the top level
13.30 configure.ac:207: error: Unexpanded AX_ macro found. Please install GNU autoconf-archive.
13.30       If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
13.30       See the Autoconf documentation.
13.31 autoreconf: error: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
------
Dockerfile:24
--------------------
  23 |     # Build and install libgpiod version 2
  24 | >>> RUN cd /tmp/libgpiod && \
  25 | >>>     ./autogen.sh && \
  26 | >>>     make && \
  27 | >>>     make install && \
  28 | >>>     ldconfig
  29 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cd /tmp/libgpiod &&     ./autogen.sh &&     make &&     make install &&     ldconfig" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Seens that autoconf.sh needs specific parameters or variables.
How can I solve this problem and properly compile the libgpiod-dev version 2.x.x?
EDIT
Have installed GNU autoconf-archive, now I'm getting the following error:
./autogen.sh 
autoreconf: export WARNINGS=
autoreconf: Entering directory '.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
aclocal: warning: couldn't open directory 'm4': No such file or directory
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: creating directory autostuff
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, 'autostuff'.
libtoolize: copying file 'autostuff/ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Intltool
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gtkdoc
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
configure.ac:77: warning: The macro `AC_HEADER_STDC' is obsolete.
configure.ac:77: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/headers.m4:704: AC_HEADER_STDC is expanded from...
configure.ac:77: the top level
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
configure.ac:53: installing 'autostuff/ar-lib'
configure.ac:53: installing 'autostuff/compile'
configure.ac:59: installing 'autostuff/config.guess'
configure.ac:59: installing 'autostuff/config.sub'
configure.ac:39: installing 'autostuff/install-sh'
configure.ac:39: installing 'autostuff/missing'
bindings/cxx/Makefile.am: installing 'autostuff/depcomp'
autoreconf: Leaving directory '.'
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for ar... ar
checking the archiver (ar) interface... ar
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for g++ option to enable C++11 features... none needed
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for file... file
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /usr/bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /usr/bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for egrep... (cached) /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for ioctl... yes
checking for open... yes
checking for close... yes
checking for read... yes
checking for ppoll... yes
checking for realpath... yes
checking for readlink... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for getopt.h... yes
checking for dirent.h... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking for sys/sysmacros.h... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for linux/const.h... yes
checking for linux/ioctl.h... yes
checking for linux/types.h... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for doxygen... true
checking for help2man... true
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: error: conditional "HAS_GI_DOCGEN" was never defined.
Usually this means the macro was only invoked conditionally.

Where does HAS_GI_DOCGEN comes from and how to set it?

The error says, "Please install GNU autoconf-archive", but you have not installed the autoconf-archive package.

OK. Have installed GNU autoconf-archive and getting another error. Will update the post


Where does HAS_GI_DOCGEN comes from and how to set it?

If we look in configure.ac, we see that HAS_GI_DOCGEN should be defined here:
if test "x$with_bindings_glib" = xtrue
then
        PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GLIB], [glib-2.0 >= 2.54])
        PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GOBJECT], [gobject-2.0 >= 2.54])
        PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GIO], [gio-2.0 >= 2.54])
        PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GIO_UNIX], [gio-unix-2.0 >= 2.54])
        PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG([0.28])
        PKG_CHECK_VAR([GLIB_MKENUMS], [glib-2.0], [glib_mkenums], [],
                AC_MSG_ERROR([glib-mkenums not found - needed to build GLib bindings]))

        AC_CHECK_PROG([has_gi_docgen], [gi-docgen], [true], [false])
        AM_CONDITIONAL([HAS_GI_DOCGEN], [test "x$has_gi_docgen" = xtrue])
        if test "x$has_gi_docgen" = xfalse
        then
                AC_MSG_NOTICE([gi-docgen not found - GLib documentation cannot be generated])
        fi
fi

But that only happens inside the if test "x$with_bindings_glib" = xtrue block. What sets with_bindings_glib? That comes from here:
AC_ARG_ENABLE([bindings-glib],
        [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-bindings-glib],[enable GLib 2.0 bindings [default=no]])],
        [if test "x$enableval" = xyes; then with_bindings_glib=true; fi],
        [with_bindings_glib=false])

Which means there is a --enable-bindings-glib parameter:
$ ./configure --help | grep bindings-glib
  --enable-bindings-glib  enable GLib 2.0 bindings [default=no]

I think this is a bug in the configure code, but we can work around that by setting the --enable-bindings-glib option. If we try setting that, we find that we have a new dependency:
$ ./configure --enable-bindings-glib
.
.
.
checking for glib-2.0 >= 2.54... no
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.54) were not met:

Package 'glib-2.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

So we need to install the libglib2.0-dev package:
apt -y install libglib2.0-dev

And now ./configure --enable-bindings-glib completes successfully. A working version of your Dockerfile might look like this:
FROM debian:bookworm-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    git \
    cmake \
    pkg-config \
    libtool \
    autoconf \
    autoconf-archive \
    doxygen \
    help2man \
    automake \
    libglib2.0-dev

RUN git clone https://github.com/brgl/libgpiod.git /tmp/libgpiod

# Build and install libgpiod version 2
RUN cd /tmp/libgpiod && \
    ./autogen.sh --enable-bindings-glib && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig


This is unrelated to your question, but I wanted to make a couple of comments about your Dockerfile. When you do this:
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
    package1 \
    package2
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

You are not reducing the size of your image (you are actually increasing the size by a small amount). If you want that apt-get clean to be effective, it needs to be part of the same RUN command as the install so that Docker doesn't save the resulting cached files in the image layer. That is, you need:
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
    package1 \
    package2 \
    && \
  apt-get clean && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

The case when calling apt-get remove later on in the Dockerfile is similar; while the packages that you remove won't be visible in the final image, you won't reduce the size of the image. What you're doing is a good candidate for a multistage build. That might look like this:
##
## FIRST STAGE: Set up the build environment and compile the code
##
FROM debian:bookworm-slim AS builder

# Install necessary tools for building from source
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    git \
    cmake \
    pkg-config \
    libtool \
    autoconf \
    autoconf-archive \
    doxygen \
    help2man \
    automake \
    libglib2.0-dev \

# Clone the libgpiod repository
RUN git clone https://github.com/brgl/libgpiod.git /tmp/libgpiod

# Build and install libgpiod version 2
RUN cd /tmp/libgpiod && \
    ./autogen.sh --enable-bindings-glib && \
    make && \
    make install DESTDIR=/tmp/installroot && \
    ldconfig

##
## SECOND STAGE: This creates the final image
##
FROM debian:bookworm-slim

COPY --from=builder /tmp/installroot/ /

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install \
    libglib2.0-0 \
  && \
  apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

The advantage here is that the build dependencies are completely absent from the final image...they were never installed in the first place! The only content we preserve from the builder stage is what we installed into /tmp/installroot.

Uau, above my expectations - thanks a lot for the super detalied post and the Docker lession... Got my respect.
